# Convert Column from BigInt to DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, type-conversion, bigint

I know this has been asked a bunch on here but example I have tried throws errors for me.

I have a table that is pulling is user data from AD. There is a column for Password Expire time, and Password last set time.  I checked the data type of this column and it is BigInt.  I am trying to convert it to an actual date time.  This is what I am running.

```
select 
us.resourceid,
us.user_Name0,
us.displayName0,
us.department0,
us.msDS_UserPasswordExpiryTi,
us.pwdLastSet,
us.Windows_NT_Domain0
from v_R_User us 
Where (us.User_Name0 not like '%$' and us.User_Name0 not like 'HealthMailbox%' and us.User_Name0 not like 'svc%')
```

Here is an example of the data returned

```
resourceid  user_Name0  displayName0    department0 msDS_UserPasswordExpiryTi   pwdLastSet Windows_NT_Domain0
2063597569  ZZZZZ       Name0           NULL        131113622747354070          130798262747354070  Dom1
2063597572  CCCCC       Name1           Dept1       132781804234873444          132466444234873444  Dom1
2063597573  FFFFF       Name2           Dept1       132829224102270283          132513864102270283  Dom1
2063597574  FFFFFE      Name3           Dept1       132737776092485812          132422416092485812  Dom1
2063597575  YYYYYY      Name4           Dept2       132781839502628544          132466479502628544  Dom2
2063597576  VVVVVV      Name5           Dept3       132798423957001686          132483063957001686  Dom2
2063597577  GGGGG       Name6           Dept3       132750906648479589          132435546648479589  Dom2
```

I have tried running the query with the following lines to create another column with the data converted into date time but always get the error `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.`

```
dateadd(s, convert(bigint, us.msDS_UserPasswordExpiryTi) / 10000, convert(datetime, '1-1-1970 00:00:00')) 
dateadd(ms, us.msDS_UserPasswordExpiryTi / 86400000, (us.msDS_UserPasswordExpiryTi / 86400000) + 25567)
Cast(Dateadd(second, Cast(us.msDS_UserPasswordExpiryTi AS BIGINT) / 1000, '19700101') AS DATE) 
cast(cast(us.msDS_UserPasswordExpiryTi as varchar(80)) as datetime)
```

I am not sure if its an issue with the data or what.  If you just just copying one of the values out and running a select statement with any of the above lines with just the value I get the same error. etc.

```
Select dateadd(s, convert(bigint, 131113622747354070) / 10000, convert(datetime, '1-1-1970 00:00:00'))
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your timestamp seems to be measures in hundred millions of a second -- quite precise.

You can break this into two calculations, one for the date and one for the datepart.  If precision to a second is sufficient (as your question suggests), then:

```
Select dateadd(second, (131113622747354070 / 100000000) % (24 * 60 * 60),
               dateadd(day, (131113622747354070 / 100000000) / (24 * 60 * 60), '1970-01-01'))
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  That one doesn't error.  Had no clue how to tell how precise the time was broken down.  Assumed it was the same format as all the examples i saw.  Only issue is the times that are converted come back as pw expires in 2012. Should be some time in 2021. PW last set column all shows 2011 dates. which should be sometime in 2020 or 2021

Comment: `131113622747354070 130798262747354070 2011-07-20 04:30:27.000 2011-06-13 16:30:27.000`

Comment: Actually the one in the example was for an old service account, it should actually be 2015 last set, and 2016 expires.  But the others ive looked at also show 2012 - 2011 but should be 2021 - 2020.  I will be excluding any service accounts in the where statement once i can get this working.

Comment: `132781804234873444 132466444234873444 2012-01-29 06:20:42.000 2011-12-23 18:20:42.000`

Comment: Looked up what the increment of time is.  Supposedly MS stores this in nanoseconds.  That should be one billionth of second i guess.  I tried adding a 0 to what you gave but it still wasn't correct. Showed the dates as in the 70s